# Upload image using firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to upload image using firebase cloud functions from an android app that calls a function **( Call functions from your app )**, not **( Call functions via HTTP requests )**

**for example :**

```
exports.uploadImage= functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {


});
```

Comment: Why not using Cloud Storage for Firebase and the Firebase SDK for Android? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start and https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Comment: Because I'm registering a user and I want to be save by using cloud functions. So the user won't be able to manipulate my code. FYI, I'm using the firebase SDK for android but it is not safe for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase functions callable - image as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725429/firebase-functions-callable-image-as-argument)