# Firebase functions callable - image as argument

Tags: image, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function which given some arguments creates a "post" with a title and the such. Is there a way to send an image as an argument which can then be processed by firebase functions and then upload to firebase storage.

I think it is possible by decoding the file/image object to a base64 string which could be then sent as an argument. How would I convert the file object from html file input to base64? On the other side how would firebase functions know that the string is an actual image? How can I tell the size of the image? Is there a limit to the size of arguments given to a firebase **callable** function?

Comment: I'd recommend instead having the client upload the file directly to Cloud Storage before you make the function call.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes that would be a way of doing it. If you could write up an answer to this of how you would construct a firebase callable cloudfunction that would take it out of the "temp-pool", check for specific metadata and then move it to an "official pool" with  some example of the rules blocking upload to the official pool I would gladly except this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ditched this question but came across the problem later in a different project. So to anyone seeing it is possible through base 64 strings. It has the restraints that the image cannot be bigger than 10mb but it is easier than trying to "catch" the file after it being uploaded directly.

[Here is the solution](https://gist.github.com/kaleidawave/3ff8b2ddb2990237f354bd7a48ef5326)

Comment: Does this still work?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Let the user upload the file directly into firebase storage in a folder where only the user has access to.
2. Let a function trigger on upload that takes this image, checks if the user is authorized to put that in the target folder and put the file in there (or whatever you want the function to do exactly).